# Ambari Server java process died with exitcode -1

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ambari

I can't start ambari-server after finishing installation and setup of ambari-server on Ubuntu16.04. This is the error message I get:

> ERROR: Exiting with exit code -1.
>
> REASON: Ambari Server java process died with exitcode -1. Check /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out for more information.

What's more, there is only ambari-server.log instead of ambari-server.out

Could someone help me？ Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide complete console output of "ambari-server restart" command?

Comment: You should see error message "Failed to run the Ambari Server" along with exception in /var/log/ambari-server.log file just after message "- Getting the controller". Please provide this error message to get idea about why process failed to start

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you setting correctly when you run:

--> ambari-server setup

At the step Select 1 at Enter advanced database configuration to use the default, embedded PostgreSQL database for Ambari.

If you select 4, You must install postgresql before.
*** If you install with another database you research more.

Please check how many version Java installed on your OS.

### Recommendation you use Java default when install Ambari don't need to install Java before.

Thank you